# Highlighting Duplicate values from two columns in excel using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to compare two cols in excel for duplicate values across them.

I have managed to pull the data from both cols, but can't seem to highlight the duplicated values or even know if I have actually pulled duplicates

This is a sample from my DataFrame

[image: dataframe]

my code below.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('beachfront.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def duplicated(df):
    df[df.duplicated(subset=['Publisher Name', 'Supply Tag'], keep=False)]


print(df)
```

This is what I get in the terminal after running the code block

[image: Imgur]

I would just like duplicates to be highlighted within the excel sheet after I run the code.

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: It would be easier to write a quick vba script to do this after you export it to excel then try to do excel formatting using pandas.

Comment: It would be better to write data to excel sheet first and then based on duplicate values apply formatting.You can use `xlsxwriter` or `openpyxl` module for writing and formatting.

Comment: The spreadsheet is in the working dir, but ill give xlswriter a go